# c++/cli calling a native c++ method

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli

i have written a c++/cli program which calls my native c++ function which has the struct pointers as parameter to it. so its like i wrote a wrapper for my native c++ using c++/cli so that i can expose it to c# wcf program(which acts a server to another c++ client).

now when i compile my c++/cli program, i didn't get any errors and it got compiled and the dll for this c++/cli is generated, but when look at output window i see some thing like this failed in linking(which didn't effect the compilation). Below is the message that i see in the output file.

```
1>Linking...
1>Embedding manifest...
1>Caching metadata information for c:\windows\system32\msxml6.dll...
1>Could not cache metadata for c:\windows\system32\msxml6.dll: reflection failed.
```

so i want to know like what this message means and whether this will effect my c# wcf program if i am using this c++/cli dll in c# wcf program, and how can i get rid of this message.

Comment: Take a look at this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcplus2008prerelease/thread/b1127c71-6c5b-4ad0-9234-b0d57291b602

Comment: @parapura: Good find.  This indicates that it may affect rebuild times, but the resulting DLL should be perfectly usable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that MSXML6.DLL is a native DLL, therefore it doesn't have any managed metadata.

I verified this with .NET Reflector:

```
// Assembly msxml6

  Location: C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll
  Name: msxml6, 'C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll' is not a .NET module.
```

Make sure you're listing its import library in the Linker -> Input -> "Additional Dependencies" project option, and not trying to reference it as you would a .NET assembly.